# Some questions after Instagram API restriction and Instagram private api?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagramapi-mgp25

I'm doing an Instagram application. Firstly wanted to use the Instagram's Endpoints. But many features were closed. User search, follower, following list etc.

Instagram announced that it will close many Endpoints on July 31st. Nowadays, I expect all 3rd party applications to become inoperable. But they were all still working.

First of all, I thought they would parse HTML instead of using the info API. When I'm looking at I've seen the use of the Private Instagram API instead of the Instagram Endpoints.

I am confused at this point.

1. If the Instagram closes the endpoints, how do the private APIs access this information?
2. Below is the private API is written for C#. For example, it wants my username and password to be able to access my follower list. If Endpoints do not exist knowing the username and password, how can the application access my information? What should I investigate to understand this issue better?

   https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper
3. Private API needs a username and password to access the story of the user. In this way, I could access the stories of the people I followed. However, I could access the story of a public account without login by searching for the username in the following site. How to access user's story information without login?

   https://storiesig.com
4. I understand that when I want to use the private API completely, people need to give me their username and password. Can I use private API over token after login with Instagram? It does not make sense to have a screen that will get the username and password. Can such an application be put into the market?
5. Can not access a user list of a Public account with HTML without using the private API? How do they have risks?

The questions I ask may be incomplete and mistake. Sorry for the spelling mistakes is not my native.

Comment: your question is interesting, did you learn anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Private api is primary api of instagram android app that export from revearse enginering of mobile app and is  different with instagram official api
2. You must first call login endpoint with username and password parameter and then call another api
3. You can not access any api without login because this is private api
4. Sorry, you can not use access token with instagram private api and you must use username and password for login
5. For do this you should use offcial instagram api

Answer (score 0):

You can view and download anonymously via the Private API . 
Many websites use it, i personally prefer this one , runs smoothly, have a look:
https://instastoriesdownload.com

All you need is to setup the Private API with a dummy account in order to access the data and you are done.

Comment: You can also try using https://storiesig.org to see instagram stories or save them.